# Task to create files/folders when they don't exist in grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm trying to automate my testing and was wanting to automatically create test files for any javascript that is created on src folder. Here's a break down on my folder structure.

```
js
--src
  --sum.js
  --subtract.js
  --calculator.js
  --innerFolder
    --multiply.js
    --divide.js
--specs
```

So from the above folder structure what I want to do is create all the folder structure and files on my specs like this only **if the file on the destination folder doesn't already exist** :-

```
js
--src
  --sum.js
  --subtract.js
  --calculator.js
  --innerFolder
    --multiply.js
    --divide.js
--specs
  --sumSpec.js
  --subtractSpec.js
  --calculator.js
  --innerFolder
    --multiplySpec.js
    --divideSpec.js
```

My approach to tackle this is by watching all the files/folders on src folder doing :-

```
watch:{
  src : {
    files: ['src/**/*.*'],
    tasks:  //create files and folders on specs folders here
}
```

I came across [grunt.file](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/grunt.file) plugin and also have considered [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) and making my own script to achieve this.

But I was wondering if there was already an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the copy task along with the filter property:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  copy: {
    js: {
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'js/src',
      src: '**/*.js',
      dest: 'js/specs',
      filter: function(filepath) {
        var path = require('path');
        var dest = path.join(
          grunt.config('copy.js.dest'),
          // Remove the parent 'js/src' from filepath
          filepath.split(path.sep).slice(2).join(path.sep)
        );
        return !(grunt.file.exists(dest));
      },
    },
  },
  watch: {
    js: {
      files: ['js/src/**/*.js'],
      tasks: ['copy:js'],
    },
  },
});
```

Then you can have it copy files that don't exist as you edit or run `grunt copy:js`.

Comment: For some reason the filter !grunt.file.exists(filepath) is always returning true even though the dest directory is empty.

Comment: grunt.file.exists just checks if the file or dir exists, not whether it is empty.

Comment: Sorry I meant grunt.file.exists(filepath) is always returning true which is causing !grunt.file.exists to be false everytime and that's why none of the files are being copied over.

Comment: Oh you're right, my mistake. It needs `nonull: true` to match non-existent files. I've updated the example.

Comment: Still no luck. :( I've also updated my question if I wasn't clear on my original post. I wanted to copy all the files/folders from src to dest folder on a condition that if there already exists a file on the destination folder with the same name as src then the copy command is to skip that file.
Right now with your solution, I think the copy is only checking if there exists a file on src folder only and not checking on the destination folder.

Comment: Okay, let's try it one more time :) I've updated my example to operate on the destination rather than the src.

Comment: You have no idea how thankful I am to you right now. :') I owe you two beers if we ever come across in life. Also, thank you for being very patience with my not-so clear post. You're awesome.